# Pouchdb encryption compatible with pouch find

Tags: javascript, encryption, indexeddb, web-sql, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB and am trying to find a solution that would encrypt the local DB without compromising pouchdb-find.

From what I understand, pouchdb-crypto encrypts each document so pouchdb-find won't work...

Is it possible to encrypt the whole DB? Or is there any solution that would suit my requirements (encryption + find)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?I am thriving to find the solution of exact same problem. if you did find a way to do it, please tell me. it would be very useful.